# Ruby Method That Returns The Median Integer In Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, median

I want to write a method that finds the median of a given array of integers. Can someone explain what is wrong/going on in my code. If the array has an odd number of integers, it returns the middle item from the sorted array. If the array has an even number of integers, return the average of the middle two items from the sorted array. Below is my code, which keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
def median_finder(array)
  array.sort
  element_count = array.length 

  if element_count % 2 != 0
    while element_count != 1 do
      array.shift
      array.pop
    end 

    return array
  else element_count % 2 == 0
    while element_count != 2 do
        array.shift
        array.pop
    end 
    median = ((array[0] + array[1]) / 2)
    return median   
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loops do not alter the variable `element_count`, and so the condition of the loop never change, looping forever. `element_count` always remains the value of the size of the original array. A quick fix is below:

```
...
while element_count != 1 do
  array.shift
  array.pop
  element_count = array.length
end
...
while element_count != 2 do
  array.shift
  array.pop
  element_count = array.length
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that while my answer fixes your specific problem, it's not really the ruby-esque way. You should definitely look at the other answers on your question, especially Uri Agassi's use of `inject` and the Tin Man's use of `odd?` and array slicing (`array[1..-2]`). These are examples of using the language's features to your advantage and not solving problems that have already been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `array.sort` is wrong. It should be `array.sort!`.

Instead of:

```
if element_count % 2 != 0
```

Use:

```
if element_count.odd?
```

Instead of:

```
array.shift
array.pop
```

Consider:

```
array = array[1..-2]
```

`else` doesn't take a condition. This is wrong:

```
else element_count % 2 == 0
```

One of these would work:

```
else
```

Or:

```
else # element_count % 2 == 0
```

Be very careful with this sort of logic:

```
element_count != 1
```

What happens if `array` has two elements and you remove them? `element_count` will be 0 and the conditional test will still not have been met, so the code will continue looping.

Instead use a test like:

```
element_count >1
```

Comment: I don't think using `array.sort!` is appropriate in this case since the order of array will change after `median_finder` is called. `array = array.sort` would be better.

Comment: `array.sort!` is the same as `array = array.sort`. `sort!` modifies the receiver.

Comment: @theTinMan - what ymonad is saying that `sort!` will affect the caller of `median_finder` method. `array = array.sort` is different, since it creates a new array (overriding the parameter with a local variable), while `sort!` _modifies_ the parameter itself.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's true.

Comment: `array.sort!` is *not at all* the same as `array = array.sort`, precisely *because* `sort!` modifies the receiver and `sort` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the number of elements in the array, it would be simpler using math (= dividing the length by two) instead of looping:

```
def median_finder(array)
  array = array.sort
  if array.length.odd?
    array[array.length / 2]
  else
    array[array.length / 2 - 1, 2].inject(:+) / 2.0
  end
end
```

`inject(:+)` is the ruby way of doing sum. `array[array.length / 2 - 1, 2]` takes the two elements in the middle of the array, so you could actually replace that line with something like this:

```
    median1, median2 = array[array.length / 2 - 1, 2]
    (median1 + median2) / 2.0
```

Comment: hi Uri, the inject method always confuses me. could you explain to me what is going in the 'else' portion of your suggestion. i understand that you are trying to call the 'median' element in the even array, but I don't understand what the inject is doing. thanks man.

Comment: @jomonavi - I've added some more explanations